# How to manage a large dataset using Spring MySQL and RowCallbackHandler

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to go over each row of a table in MySQL using Spring and a JdbcTemplate.  If I'm not mistaken this should be as simple as:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
template.setFetchSize(1);
// template.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE) does not work either            
template.query("SELECT * FROM cdr", new RowCallbackHandler() {
  public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("src"));
  }
});
```

I get an OutOfMemoryError because it is trying to read the whole thing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, care to change the accepted answer.  Your question was about spring and @scompt.com's answer is more appropriate.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Statement#setFetchSize()` [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) already states:

> *Gives the JDBC driver a **hint** as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database*

The driver is actually free to apply or ignore the hint. Some drivers ignore it, some drivers applies it directly, some drivers needs more parameters. The MySQL JDBC driver falls in the last category. If you check the [MySQL JDBC driver documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html), you'll see the following information (scroll about 2/3 down until header ***ResultSet***):

> To enable this functionality, you need to create a Statement instance in the following manner:
>
> ```
> stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
> stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
> ```

Please read the *entire* section of the document, it describes the caveats of this approach as well.

To get it to work in Spring, you'll however need to extend/override the JdbcTemplate with a custom implementation. As I don't do Spring I can't go in detail about this, but now you at least know where to look.

Good luck.

Comment: I've added a Spring-based solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095490/how-to-manage-a-large-dataset-using-spring-mysql-and-rowcallbackhandler/2834590#2834590

Answer (score 19):

Here's a Spring solution based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095490/how-to-manage-a-large-dataset-using-spring-mysql-and-rowcallbackhandler/2097500#2097500) provided by BalusC.

```
class StreamingStatementCreator implements PreparedStatementCreator {
    private final String sql;

    public StreamingStatementCreator(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        return statement;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code:

```
DataSource dataSource = ...;
RowCallbackHandler rowHandler = ...;
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.query(new StreamingStatementCreator("SELECT * FROM huge_table"), rowHandler);
```

Comment: worth noting that you need to make sure that useServerPrepStmts property in your connection string is set properly, i.e. if by any chance this set to false ^^ won't work and it will cache full result set

Comment: It is worth noting that with Spring 3 the JdbcTemplate's setFetchSize ignores limits less than 1 and so you HAVE to override a very basic feature.  Yuck.

Comment: @AndrewGilmartin  After 4.3, should work-
Note: As of 4.3, negative values other than -1 will get passed on to the driver, since e.g. MySQL supports special behavior for Integer.MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect you are getting the OutOfMemory error due to the entire table read, why dont you try splitting your query. Use filters, LIMIT clause etc.

Comment: That would cause the logic of the process to be much more complex.  I'm now testing a way to actually do the streaming via the Spring JdbcTeamplate.  Will let you know if it works...