# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate setting connection fetch size property

Tags: java

We are using Spring 2.6 and we use jdbcTemplate as well as NamedparameterJdbcTemplate in our system and configurations are as follows.

```
 <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="500>
  </bean>

<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

While jdbcTemplate has a property "fetchSize", namedParameterJdbcTemplate does not have. I want to set the fetchSize for this so i came up with another constructor for namedParameterJdbcTemplate which accepts "jdbcTemplate", so i configured my bean as follows to use fetchSize of 500 which is already configured for jdbcTemplate:

```
<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"></constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

But after this i am getting following exceptions for few queries :

com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Cursor 'jconnect_implicit_16' was declared with a FOR UPDATE clause. This cursor was found to be read only.

```
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:121)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:582)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:616)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:123)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:127)
```

Can someone please suggest its solution?

Comment: Could you add an example of one of the failing queries?

Comment: Hi Tomas, One of the query is : SELECT TCRT.assessment_id,TCRT.asset_id,ROUND (TCRT.rcrt_value,0) as rcrt_value,ra_rcrt_codes.rcrt_name,ra_rcrt_codes.rcrt_short_desc,ra_rcrt_codes.rcrt_long_desc FROM ra_assess_rcrt_values TCRT inner join ra_rcrt_codes on TCRT.rcrt_id = ra_rcrt_codes.rcrt_id and TCRT.active = 1 and ra_rcrt_codes.rcrt_name not like 'TAM%'and ra_rcrt_codes.active = 1 and TCRT.asset_id In (:appId1).                                                            I guess this might be the problem with ROUND function which i am using. Because normal queries are working properly.

Comment: I have found a workaround for this by adding "for read only" to my queries which are breaking. But i dont want to apply this mechanisn as its big ask to find the queries and correct them. Can someone please suggest any othr workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the above workaround has strange side effects.

Use of JdbcTemplate.query(...) to perform selects which occasionally result in 0 rows now throw the exception

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ0R2: No result set for this query.

Another obscure problem with few results on Google (and no helpful ones).

I'm now using the solution of creating a StreamingStatementCreator as described in an answer to this question [How to manage a large dataset using Spring MySQL and RowCallbackHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095490/how-to-manage-a-large-dataset-using-spring-mysql-and-rowcallbackhandler)

This creates a Statement that has ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY set, but you can still use JdbcTemplate, rather than reverting back to Connections, Statements and ResultSets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting this exception.
It's related to `Sybase` `jConnect` for `JDBC`.

I found [this](http://search.sybase.com/kbx/changerequests?bug_id=619057) workaround.

To quote the `Sybase` Programmers Reference `jConnect` for `JDBC 6.05`

There is no known advantage to setting `LANGUAGE_CURSOR` to true,
but the option is provided in case an application displays unexpected
behavior when `LANGUAGE_CURSOR` is false.

Comment: I would give you a hundred up votes if I could, thank you so much!

Comment: Link is not working. Can you provide some details about it here.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all your mappings and make sure they are ok! Look for the proper types. This issue is normally caused by a lower level exception that is thrown up and caught by the SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator. Normally it has something to do with the improper map object type.

Comment: Hi ozziefel, I went through the queries and this issue is occuring for queries where i have used some aggregate functions like ROUND etc. It works fine when i append "for read only" to my query. So i think by default the cursor is set to read only while i have not specified in my query. So is there any configuration where i can modify my cursor level through code so that i need not go through my application queries and change them?