# Mysql streaming result set and jOOQ fetchLazy

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jooq

Normally when I want to query large result set using Mysql I write this (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097500/183791)):

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Now I'm using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) 2.0.5 and I can't achieve the same result.

I've tried calling `fetchLazy` with no luck, it loads the entire result set in memory:

```
Cursor<Record> result = query.fetchLazy(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

As a workaround I can get the sql query using `query.getSQL()` and create a suitable `Statement` to execute it.

Is there another way to have stream result sets using jOOQ?

Comment: Never used it myself, but a quick glance through the docs mentions that you have to setFetchSize() on the underlying statement (though that seems to defeat the purpose of the overlay...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the JDBC specs, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is not a valid argument for the [`Statement.setFetchSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) method:

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for ResultSet objects genrated by this Statement. If the value specified is zero, then the hint is ignored. The default value is zero.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **rows** the number of rows to fetch
>
> **Throws**:
>   SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement or the condition rows >= 0 is not satisfied.

Implementations may throw a `SQLException` for negative fetch sizes. Hence, jOOQ doesn't accept parameters less than 0. You should try using a fetch size of `1` instead. In the mean time, the next release of jOOQ might be able to break the JDBC standard, to support this [documented MySQL feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html)
:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1263 (implemented in jOOQ 2.2.0)

Comment: No, using a fetch size of `1` I get a `OutOfMemoryError`. I finally ended using JDBC. But I'll surely be waiting for the next jOOQ release :)

Comment: @dusan: Too bad MySQL doesn't follow the JDBC specs. But the fix will be published in a week. [A preview is available here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/jooq/)