# What does it mean when Statement.executeUpdate() returns -1?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

A query that works in management studio and in the `executeUpdate`makes that same `executeUpdate` return `-1`, which is undefined in any documentation we can find. Its supposed to return only the rowcount or `0`. What does this mean? The driver is the JDBC-ODBC bridge if that matters.

Example:

```java
String query = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal_name ='" + a +"') INSERT INTO " + table + " (animal_name, animal_desc, species_id) VALUES ('" + a + "', '" + b + "', " + c + ")";
int result = statement.executeUpdate(query);
System.out.println(result);
```

The query works, as the row is added to the database, it's just strange that it returns -1 where the documentation says it will only return 0 or the rowcount (as I've been corrected).

UPDATE:

Running this in Management Studio results with "Command completed successfully."

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM animals WHERE animal_name = 'a') 
INSERT INTO animals(animal_name, animal_desc, species_id) VALUES ('a', 'a', 1)
```

That should mean the method should return 0 because it doesn't return anything, correct?

Comment: Can you give us a piece of code showing this?

Comment: I would be very interested to see your code. And you're a little incorrect, when you say, `executeUpdate(...)` is *supposed to return only 1 or 0*...it actually returns *either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing*

Comment: cannot be -1. The executeUpdate() returns either the row count for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements, or 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Comment: Updated the question with code and corrections.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Yes, we're using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: do you use the getUpdateCount() any where in your code?

Comment: You should really consider posting your most recent edit as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Done.

Comment: This just happened to me. Someone has modified the grant statements of the procedure that I was calling and I lost the call permission on that procedure. The connection with the database is ok, but when I invoked the procedure through the Application Server, than it logged the -1 as the result of the cstmResult: int cstmResult = cstm.executeUpdate(); Fortunately it was easy to detect the cause because of the logging files: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object '...'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So 4 years later, [Microsoft has open sourced their JDBC driver on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc). I got a notification about this question today, and went and had a look, and I believe I have found the culprit [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/cfba660ac950a14da127cb9399430425473fb46f/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerStatement.java#L1713), `mssql-jdbc/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerStatement.java:1713`.

Basically, the driver tries to understand what SQL Server sends back if it is not a definite result set. According to the comments, it goes like this:

> 1. Check for errors first. (ln 1669)
> 2. Not an error.  Is it a result set? (ln 1680)
> 3. Not an error or a result set.  Maybe a result from a T-SQL statement?
>      That is, one of the following:
>
>    - a positive count of the number of rows affected (from INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE),
>    - a zero indicating no rows affected, or the statement was DDL, or
>    - **a -1 indicating the statement succeeded, but there is no update count information available** (translates to Statement.SUCCESS_NO_INFO in batch update count arrays). *(ln 1706)*
> 4. None of the above.  Last chance here...  Going into the parser above, we know moreResults was initially true.  If we come out with moreResults false, the we hit a DONE token (either DONE (FINAL) or DONE (RPC in batch)) that indicates that the batch succeeded overall, but that there is no information on individual statements' update counts.  This is similar to the last case above, except that there is no update count.  That is: we have a successful result (return true), but we have no other information about it (updateCount = -1). *(ln 1693)*
> 5. Only way to get here (moreResults is still true, but no apparent results of any kind) is if the TDSParser didn't actually parse
>      *anything*.  That is, we are at EOF in the response.  In that case, there truly are no more results.  We're done. (ln 1717)

(Emphasis mine)

So you guys were right in the end. SQL simply can't tell how many rows are affected, and defaults to `-1`. :)

Answer (score 28):

As the statement executed is not actually DML (eg `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `EXECUTE`), but a piece of T-SQL which *contains* DML, I suspect it is not treated as an update-query.

Section 13.1.2.3 of the JDBC 4.1 specification states something (rather hard to interpret btw):

> When the method `execute` returns true, the method `getResultSet` is called to
>   retrieve the ResultSet object. When `execute` returns false, the method
>   `getUpdateCount` returns an int. If this number is greater than or equal to zero, it
>   indicates the update count returned by the statement. If it is -1, it indicates that there
>   are no more results.

Given this information, I guess that `executeUpdate()` internally does an `execute()`, and then - as `execute()` will return `false` - it will return the value of `getUpdateCount()`, which in this case - in accordance with the JDBC spec - will return `-1`.

This is further corroborated by the fact 1) that the Javadoc for [`Statement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) says:

> Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

And 2) that the Javadoc for [Statement.getUpdateCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount%28%29) specifies:

> the current result as an update count; -1 if the current result is a ResultSet object or there are no more results

Just to clarify: given the Javadoc for `executeUpdate()` the behavior is probably wrong, but it can be explained.

Also as I commented elsewhere, the -1 might just indicate: maybe something was changed, but we simply don't know, or we can't give an accurate number of changes (eg because in this example it is a piece of T-SQL that is executed).

Comment: This is probably the most useful explanation for the observed behaviour of SQL Server JDBC driver behaviour. Nice thinking!

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen this anywhere, either, but my instinct would be that this means that the `IF` prevented the whole statement from executing.

Try to run the statement with a database where the `IF` passes.

Also check if there are any triggers involved which might change the result.

**[EDIT]** When [the standard says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that this function should never return `-1`, that doesn't *enforce* this. Java doesn't have pre and post conditions. A JDBC driver could return a random number and there was no way to stop it.

If it's important to know why this happens, run the statement against different database until you have tried all execution paths (i.e. one where the `IF` returns `false` and one where it returns `true`).

If it's not that important, mark it off as a "clever trick" by a Microsoft engineer and remember how much you liked it when you feel like being clever yourself next time.

Comment: The `IF` statement works, the code was pretty much copy pasted from a query in Management Studio that was tested before it was put into the program. The `INSERT` statement does work because the row is shown if you do a `SELECT` statement afterwards.

Comment: I mean "executing" as in "did it change the database" rather than "did it produce an error"

Comment: See my edit of the question. All we get from the query is "Command completed successfully"

Comment: Microsoft never *really* cared for standards unless they could use it crush the competition (see [embrace, extend and extinguish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish)). What do you get when the `IF` returns the opposite result?

Comment: The SQL Server JDBC driver isn't the only one violating JDBC API contracts. See [this question about MySQL's `Statement.setFetchSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949750/mysql-streaming-result-set-and-jooq-fetchlazy)

Comment: All JDBC drivers have ... "interesting interpretations of the standard".

Comment: @AaronDigulla Part of the problem is that the JDBC spec isn't always very clear or explicit, and they sometimes (slightly) changed semantics between JDBC versions.

Comment: BTW: The Javadoc doesn't explicitly say it can't be `-1`, maybe Microsoft decided that -1 means 'maybe something changed, but we are not sure'.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Incredibly, you're probably right (see [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12401701/521799) or [your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12412073/521799)). At last, SQL Server's JDBC driver *might somehow* adhere to the JDBC specs in some weird ways, in this case.

Comment: @AaronDigulla 8 years later I am referring this answer to my colleagues about how it feels to be caught out by a "clever trick"; that sentence has stuck with me since you said it. Thank you for influencing my career!

Answer (score 5):

For executeUpdate statements against a DB2 for z/OS server, the value that is returned depends on the type of SQL statement that is being executed:

For an SQL statement that can have an update count, such as an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, the returned value is the number of affected rows. It can be:

A positive number, if a positive number of rows are affected by the operation, and the operation is not a mass delete on a segmented table space.

0, if no rows are affected by the operation.

**-1, if the operation is a mass delete on a segmented table space.**

For a DB2 CALL statement, *a value of -1 is returned, because the DB2 database server cannot determine the number of affected rows. Calls to getUpdateCount or getMoreResults for a CALL statement also return -1.
For any other SQL statement, a value of -1 is returned.*

Comment: Although, it was a part of the comment, I believe the OP specified that the Database used is *SQL Server 2008*

Comment: @Sachin does TRUNCATE command count as "mass delete on a segmented table" ?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't explain why it should be like that, but it explains why it could happen. The following byte-code sets `-1` to the internal `updateCount` flag in the `SQLServerStatement` constructor:

```
// Method descriptor #401 (Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;II)V
// Stack: 5, Locals: 8
SQLServerStatement(
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
throws com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException;

// [...]

34 aload_0 [this]
35 iconst_m1
36 putfield com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.updateCount:int [27]
```

Now, I will not analyse all possible control-flows, but I'd just say that this is the internal default initialisation value that somehow leaks out to client code. Note, this is also done in other methods:

```
// Method descriptor #383 ()V
// Stack: 2, Locals: 1
final void resetForReexecute() 
throws com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException;

// [...]

10 aload_0 [this]
11 iconst_m1
12 putfield com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.updateCount:int [27]

// Method descriptor #383 ()V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 3
final void clearLastResult();
0 aload_0 [this]
1 iconst_m1
2 putfield com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.updateCount:int [27]
```

In other words, you're *probably* safe interpreting `-1` as being the same as `0`. If you rely on this result value, maybe stay on the safe side and do your checks as follows:

```
// No rows affected
if (stmt.executeUpdate() <= 0) {
}
// Rows affected
else {
}
```

**UPDATE**: While reading [Mark Rotteveel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12412073/521799), I tend to agree with him, assuming that `-1` is the JDBC-compliant value for *"unknown update counts"*. Even if this isn't documented on the relevant method's Javadoc, it's documented in the [JDBC specs, chapter 13.1.2.3 Returning Unknown or Multiple Results](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf). In this very case, it could be said that an `IF .. INSERT ..` statement will have an *"unknown update count"*, as this statement isn't SQL-standard compliant anyway.