# JDBC Statement interface - executeUpdate query

Tags: java, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
class ConnectionTest {
    public static void main(String... args)throws Exception {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:myjdbc1", "sri", "tiger");
        System.out.println(con);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println(st);
        String query = "delete logindetails";
        int count = st.executeUpdate(query);
        if(count == 0) 
        System.out.println("no records to delete");
        else 
        System.out.println("deleted successfullly");
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Hello World..!!
My Question is..
What value is being assigned to integer variable `count` in `int count = st.executeUpdate(query);`
What does it assigns after it deleted all the rows..
and what does it assigns if there are already 0 rows in my table and no rows are deleted..?

Detailed explanation is much appreciated.
P.S. noob here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400985/what-does-it-mean-when-statement-executeupdate-returns-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

executeUpdate(query) returns number of rows affected this implies if there are no rows in the table then 0 will be returned and if there are rows in table then total rowcount of table.

Comment: Done. I dont think too much explanation is needed, its straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

From [official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29): 
Returns:
either the **row count** for SQL Data Manipulation Language (such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) statements or **0** for SQL statements that return nothing

@Update

It assigns the number of deleted rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Returns:**
either

**(1)** the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or

**(2)** 0 for SQL statements that return nothing