# Java SQL stored procedure ResultSet can't get data from results that only contain 1 row

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, resultset

I can execute the stored procedure fine and collect the results when there is more than 1 row returned. However when the procedure returns 1-row ResultSet.next() always returns false so I can't get that data. Any ideas as to why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
List<Panel> panels = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String SPsql = "EXEC [dbo].[CR_Pick_Trim_Route] ?";
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://database", "username", "password");
        CallableStatement ps = conn.prepareCall(SPsql);
        ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        ps.setQueryTimeout(300);
        ps.setString(1, route);

        boolean hadResults = ps.execute();

        while (hadResults)
        {
            ResultSet reset = ps.getResultSet();

            while (reset.next()) {
                String route_name = reset.getString("route_name");
                String order_no = reset.getString("order_no");
                String product = reset.getString("pick_comp");
                String drop_no = reset.getString("drop_no");
                String desc = reset.getString("long_description");
                String analysisA = reset.getString("analysis_a");
                String consumer = reset.getString("comp_cons");
                String warehouse = reset.getString("pick_wh");
                String key = reset.getString("Key");
                int total = reset.getInt("pick_qty");
                String scanned = reset.getString("Scanned");
                String picked = reset.getString("picked");
                String original = reset.getString("original");

                Panel p = new Panel(route_name, order_no, drop_no, product, desc, analysisA, consumer, warehouse, (!picked.equals("No")), key, total, (scanned.contains("Y")), original);
                panels.add(p);
            }
            hadResults = ps.getMoreResults();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found someone has asked similar question in the below link :

[why executeUpdate() method returns -1 with callable statement instead of update count or 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679356/why-executeupdate-method-returns-1-with-callable-statement-instead-of-update)

Hope it helps.