# Get Rows By Group MySQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, large-data

I have a large amount of data and I need to process them by group.
Having the table structure in the image[image]

How do I retrieve them by group? (First get group 1, process. Next, get group 2, process.. and so on.) The grouping is based on the *pos* column which should be equal.

I have been reading up on references on doing a basic join of the same table but it is not possible for me as it returns a very large set of data which will result to OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Use limit and offset. So that you can fetch the required number of entries. Then you can process it without OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: This is fine to implement paging for a GUI. I you have to iterate a big dataset this is extremely slow, since the database has to process internally all records until it reaches the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two cursors, one to select distinct groups, another to process each group separately.

```java
 //Assuming you have a Connection conn;
 PreparedStatement groupsPS = 
     conn.prepareStatement("SELECT distinct pos from yourtable");
 ResultSet groupsRS = groupsPS.executeQuery();
 PreparedStatement groupdataPS = 
     conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from yourtable where pos = ?");
 ResultSet groupdataRS = null;

 while(groupsRS.next())
 {
    groupdataPS.setString(1, groupsRS.getString("pos"));
    groupdataRS = groupdataPS.executeQuery();
    while(groupsRS.next())
    {
      //process your data here
    }
    groupdataRS.close();
 }
 groupsRS.close();
 groupdataPS.close();
 groupsPS.close();
```

Comment: As the logic is fine, this actually causes a select n+1 problem making it very slow.

Comment: @BetaRide Unless there's an index on `pos`, indeed. OP didn't want speed, though, he wanted smaller result chunks. Let's not forget that he'll also need ordering by `pos` column to process everything by group in a single query, which in turn can slow everything down.

Comment: I based my newly restructured tables in your algorithm and made use of an indexing table to solve my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Rewrite your sql to make sure you get smaller resultsets and read the whole data in junks.
2. Use a ScrollableResultset. This allows you to get row by row without loading the whole resultset into memory.

Comment: Are you sure that a scrollable result set prevents MySQL JDBC from loading the entire result in memory, though? I couldn't find anything relevant in the docs, and the solutions to memory problem, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095490 , instead suggest using ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, while scrollable result set implies TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer to the linked question clearly states how to deal with MySql and scrolling result sets.

Comment: I followed our option #1 and restructured my tables. I have posted an answer in this thread. Thank you!

Comment: @BetaRide wait a second. Scrollable result set means `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` or `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` - that is, you can go backwards if you need. `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` means non-scrollable result set, so only `next()` is available. If you meant "scrollable" as "processed row-by-row", then JDBC `ResultSet` is scrollable by design, mysql just needs special tinkering to prevent it from optimizing by loading everything in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @TimeKiller and @BetaRide mentioned, I restructured my SQL tables and added an indexing table for my *pos* with its frequency as another column.

Using this, I can just iterate through each *pos* with a frequency >= 2, get the rows in the table above with the selected *pos*, and process them.

Thanks!

Comment: Good that it's working for you. If you want to speed up the selects, you should use an [actual index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) though; also, please accept either of three answers.